# Time Plot not showing months/dates on x-axis

Tags: r, date, plot, time-series

I am working on a time series daily data. I want to plot the predictions in such a way that I get months at the bottom, but I am only getting "1" on the x-axis. This is also creating problems for forecasting the data for the next 3 months using Arima.

Here is my code.

```
data = NG020001
str(data)
NG020001 <- data

max_Date = max(NG020001$date)
max_Date # "31/10/2021"
min_Date = min(NG020001$date)
min_Date # "01/04/2021"

Y = ts(NG020001[,3], frequency = 365)
str(Y)

# Time-Series [1:214] from 1 to 1.58: 366 348 366 365 361 ...
```

I think the problem is, it should be saying April to October, rather than from 1 to 1.58

```
autoplot(Y) +
  ggtitle("Time Plot") +
  ylab("Predictions of NG020001")
```

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRO9Q.png][1]

Data: From Months 4 to 10

```
date    product pred
2021-04-01  garri   366.1540473
2021-04-02  garri   347.5080909
2021-04-03  garri   365.7266518
2021-04-04  garri   364.9078403
2021-04-05  garri   361.4496767
2021-04-06  garri   352.1568195
2021-04-07  garri   361.2184578
2021-04-08  garri   367.6160283
2021-04-09  garri   356.3464547
2021-04-10  garri   366.5382333
2021-04-11  garri   362.4359305
2021-04-12  garri   377.2999141
2021-04-13  garri   367.2380223
2021-04-14  garri   379.9699823
2021-04-15  garri   386.477677
2021-04-16  garri   371.9703246
2021-04-17  garri   377.4620738
2021-04-18  garri   381.4661889
2021-04-19  garri   371.3215164
2021-04-20  garri   387.7331647
2021-04-21  garri   386.8546853
2021-04-22  garri   380.9697565
2021-04-23  garri   378.9551942
2021-04-24  garri   383.3575161
2021-04-25  garri   370.1942208
2021-04-26  garri   378.5501389
2021-04-27  garri   383.2594843
2021-04-28  garri   380.3052176
2021-04-29  garri   378.1375864
2021-04-30  garri   377.0554622
2021-05-01  garri   378.9257948
2021-05-02  garri   383.8503831
2021-05-03  garri   395.8181258
2021-05-04  garri   374.5602337
2021-05-05  garri   369.2400232
2021-05-06  garri   381.8017709
2021-05-07  garri   386.4163408
2021-05-08  garri   375.1134861
2021-05-09  garri   382.2126922
2021-05-10  garri   379.5960517
2021-05-11  garri   375.7880494
2021-05-12  garri   420.3823821
2021-05-13  garri   401.1994222
2021-05-14  garri   427.2274604
2021-05-15  garri   412.8351273
2021-05-16  garri   399.043889
2021-05-17  garri   388.7902098
2021-05-18  garri   392.0820912
2021-05-19  garri   396.1982484
2021-05-20  garri   388.4642072
2021-05-21  garri   394.2022837
2021-05-22  garri   382.386154
2021-05-23  garri   386.0570001
2021-05-24  garri   387.4032843
2021-05-25  garri   398.0890858
2021-05-26  garri   401.9528422
2021-05-27  garri   391.4550111
2021-05-28  garri   400.641269
2021-05-29  garri   404.5307061
2021-05-30  garri   396.0913368
2021-05-31  garri   405.8905929
2021-06-01  garri   410.5151587
2021-06-02  garri   405.7189894
2021-06-03  garri   397.8324181
2021-06-04  garri   414.1571808
2021-06-05  garri   409.6032333
2021-06-06  garri   410.1884341
2021-06-07  garri   423.2927612
2021-06-08  garri   416.9968912
2021-06-09  garri   417.5089877
2021-06-10  garri   420.6469587
2021-06-11  garri   409.220872
2021-06-12  garri   420.4509089
2021-06-13  garri   420.3105285
2021-06-14  garri   442.5146041
2021-06-15  garri   485.0044875
2021-06-16  garri   430.993181
2021-06-17  garri   493.5804263
2021-06-18  garri   428.4878822
2021-06-19  garri   426.316261
2021-06-20  garri   445.2012169
2021-06-21  garri   439.373511
2021-06-22  garri   466.6277523
2021-06-23  garri   474.0429139
2021-06-24  garri   455.1581489
2021-06-25  garri   471.5804988
2021-06-26  garri   458.2035266
2021-06-27  garri   459.6874298
2021-06-28  garri   420.5177093
2021-06-29  garri   431.9606991
2021-06-30  garri   509.9281627
2021-07-01  garri   453.1682754
2021-07-02  garri   530.6647868
2021-07-03  garri   499.537223
2021-07-04  garri   491.7147224
2021-07-05  garri   509.855236
2021-07-06  garri   480.9133627
2021-07-07  garri   467.3794784
2021-07-08  garri   486.622358
2021-07-09  garri   541.7647586
2021-07-10  garri   504.404069
2021-07-11  garri   476.1447898
2021-07-12  garri   570.4844423
2021-07-13  garri   596.4433523
2021-07-14  garri   512.3478628
2021-07-15  garri   579.9675927
2021-07-16  garri   739.0191306
2021-07-17  garri   551.2706027
2021-07-18  garri   672.9939382
2021-07-19  garri   463.4308493
2021-07-20  garri   495.3774588
2021-07-21  garri   526.4449797
2021-07-22  garri   497.6159721
2021-07-23  garri   543.2950865
2021-07-24  garri   583.4469806
2021-07-25  garri   529.8636271
2021-07-26  garri   480.2293446
2021-07-27  garri   475.0231109
2021-07-28  garri   481.4105752
2021-07-29  garri   500.6937995
2021-07-30  garri   466.1686779
2021-07-31  garri   507.4191085
2021-08-01  garri   471.0945177
2021-08-02  garri   555.8589889
2021-08-03  garri   590.5580661
2021-08-04  garri   507.6571759
2021-08-05  garri   545.0577347
2021-08-06  garri   518.9370512
2021-08-07  garri   502.053694
2021-08-08  garri   530.4063154
2021-08-09  garri   709.0120415
2021-08-10  garri   652.8980092
2021-08-11  garri   514.7735684
2021-08-12  garri   553.5594962
2021-08-13  garri   501.0622007
2021-08-14  garri   618.3366549
2021-08-15  garri   472.4437285
2021-08-16  garri   522.3260871
2021-08-17  garri   514.3878131
2021-08-18  garri   469.9364089
2021-08-19  garri   536.2495878
2021-08-20  garri   509.3689204
2021-08-21  garri   490.5250789
2021-08-22  garri   591.305436
2021-08-23  garri   541.5182125
2021-08-24  garri   566.6632512
2021-08-25  garri   546.280561
2021-08-26  garri   566.5638959
2021-08-27  garri   564.8025805
2021-08-28  garri   546.5869992
2021-08-29  garri   703.3329433
2021-08-30  garri   606.3765482
2021-08-31  garri   510.2394513
2021-09-01  garri   682.9624761
2021-09-02  garri   511.2967957
2021-09-03  garri   630.0671401
2021-09-04  garri   642.2038856
2021-09-05  garri   632.4658301
2021-09-06  garri   484.4629535
2021-09-07  garri   628.3012052
2021-09-08  garri   642.7910768
2021-09-09  garri   643.7724604
2021-09-10  garri   617.6955016
2021-09-11  garri   479.4085757
2021-09-12  garri   593.7633585
2021-09-13  garri   603.0413738
2021-09-14  garri   600.2560332
2021-09-15  garri   541.8920355
2021-09-16  garri   521.6810131
2021-09-17  garri   486.7525914
2021-09-18  garri   548.937974
2021-09-19  garri   586.7846192
2021-09-20  garri   514.2732106
2021-09-21  garri   568.1856327
2021-09-22  garri   500.8542054
2021-09-23  garri   584.8080224
2021-09-24  garri   515.3924555
2021-09-25  garri   524.2928828
2021-09-26  garri   614.9216175
2021-09-27  garri   520.4179214
2021-09-28  garri   569.4791552
2021-09-29  garri   516.6360472
2021-09-30  garri   486.0530745
2021-10-01  garri   512.6467437
2021-10-02  garri   565.8942665
2021-10-03  garri   519.7620943
2021-10-04  garri   505.4966912
2021-10-05  garri   551.5491798
2021-10-06  garri   493.731323
2021-10-07  garri   519.838912
2021-10-08  garri   485.4882898
2021-10-09  garri   536.1125972
2021-10-10  garri   575.2688034
2021-10-11  garri   608.1898244
2021-10-12  garri   559.6923341
2021-10-13  garri   593.8488519
2021-10-14  garri   603.5326388
2021-10-15  garri   604.2794354
2021-10-16  garri   589.4343474
2021-10-17  garri   580.3538367
2021-10-18  garri   623.6976341
2021-10-19  garri   611.8578887
2021-10-20  garri   618.3596967
2021-10-21  garri   590.5457706
2021-10-22  garri   576.5506999
2021-10-23  garri   597.1699831
2021-10-24  garri   672.0198315
2021-10-25  garri   644.9094012
2021-10-26  garri   662.1365323
2021-10-27  garri   521.3617837
2021-10-28  garri   557.9205761
2021-10-29  garri   498.1039547
2021-10-30  garri   593.8818645
2021-10-31  garri   492.7270352
```

Comment: Your code doesn't run for me. `Error in autoplot():
! Objects of type ts not supported by autoplot.`

Comment: And is the data you provided the input, or the result? It's not clear from your code.

Comment: Everything is working fine on my end, The data I provided is input data.

Comment: If the `pred` column is already part of your input, then why are you calculating another time series in this code? Do you just want to plot `pred` against the dates?

Comment: yes. so, that I won't get "1" at the bottom. And why it is showing 1 to 1.58 rather than dates? Pred column has a range of 7 months. I just want to forecast it for the next 3 months using Arima. But, when I do it It only gives me 1 value for all the future data points. In short I just want months at the bottom rather than 1 to 1.58.

Comment: Try `ggplot(data = NG020001, aes(x = date, y = pred)) + geom_line()`

Comment: It works fine thanks a lot. But, what If I want to run auto. Arima to get the forecast for the next 3 months, should I convert the pred column into a ts object and set the frequency to 365!